# Hide Lwc Tab based on Metadata

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata, lightning-tab

I have a lwc component(called "Tab1") made as a lightning tab and have a custom metadata(called "Enable Tab1") in a different lightning page as a toggle. Then ,need to hide and show that tab("Tab1") based on a metadata on/off("Enable Tab1"). does anyone has suggestion?

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve by putting your code here with some wireframes.

Comment: @WayneNi thank you for the response.I do not have any design,but only requirement i have for the moment. I have to show and hidden the tab based on custom metadata on off